# How do I make spotlight activate applications based on path instead of Bundle Identifier?

Tags: applications, spotlight

I use multiple copies of the same app on my system. New copies are added and removed on a daily basis. I change the name of the app so they have unique names, which is convenient when using Spotlight, which lists the apps as expected.

Prior to Mac OS Ventura, Spotlight successfully launched these as separate processes, even if another instance was running in different folder. With Ventura however, this has changed so that the app is activated based on Bundle ID (I have tested this), if it is already running instead of launched.

The result of this is that while I can find my different copies of the apps, *I can only start one of them through Spotlight*. To start another, I must (for example) ⌘-click on the search result, and open it with the mouse or ⌘-DownArrow.

Changing the Bundle IDs of the copies is not something I am inclined to do, even if I can. Does anybody know of a solution for this?

Note: If you wish to repeat this issue, you might use [VLC](http://get.videolan.org/vlc/3.0.18/macosx/vlc-3.0.18-arm64.dmg). Put it in /Applications and duplicate it. Start the original, then use Spotlight and try to invoke the duplicate. Spotlight will activate the original running one, even though it is running in a different path than the one you selected. Double-click the copy in finder instead, and a new instance is started as expected. This behaviour was introduced in Mac OS Ventura, in prior Mac OS versions Spotlight  started the one you selected instead of activating the running one based on Bundle ID.

Comment: It would be easier to give help if you were to disclose the name of the app and its bundle id.

Comment: Why? Any app that supports multiple invocations can be used to test. For example, VLC can be used to repeat the problem. This is an OS/Spotlight problem, not an app problem.

Comment: Updated descriptions with steps to repeat for those that need it.

Comment: Sorry, I can reproduce the problem with, in my case, ForkLift. So agree it is a macOS problem. I would add that using search in Finder, getting the two results and opening each of them works as expected. It also works as expected when I use Alfred or HoudahSpot (both use spotlight index) to find the and run the two copies. So seems like a command-space Spotlight issue rather than an indexing issue.

Comment: I have been plowing through preference plists and strings of various spotlight-related binaries to find something that could change the behaviour back to what it was, but to no avail. Very frustrating! I have filed a Radar report.

Comment: Spotlight indexes Applications through the LaunchServices Database.  When you duplicate an App and rename it, there is no new entry within LaunchServices so Spotlight doesn’t find it. There’s no .plist to change  this behavior, it’s how spotlight works.  If you want spotlight to work as intended  you need to register the modified App with LaunchServices…and that is a development question

Comment: @Allan I'm not sure you're entirely correct. I have tried doing "  LSRegisterURL((CFURLRef)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL] autorelease],true);" on start up, and the Spotlight behaviour does not change. Do you know of a command-line way of updating LaunchServices that I can test with?

Comment: I know you have to create an application bundle specific to the app you want to register.  I’ve done this maybe two times in the last 20 years (and not for what you’re trying to do); I just don’t remember how exactly.  .  I wrote as a comment and not as an answer to point you in what I hope to be the right direction

Comment: I'm not convinced about the LaunchServices database being the basis for the Spotlight index. For one, if that was the *only* source for the SL index, the duplicated app wouldn't show up in a search - but it does. I can imagine that the LS db is somehow used by SL to launch the selected app though. But I have failed to make any differences in behaviour by registering manually in code using LSXXX functions or NSWorkspace. LS app plist keys also weren't useful for this problem.

Comment: @LudvigA.Norin, would you please outline how you change the names of the apps? I am trying to do something similar to what you describe, changing the names of multiple copies of apps so they have unique names, on Catalina and I am having only partial success. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/463077/how-can-i-change-the-main-menu-name-of-a-copy-of-textedit-app